# Castle wcf facility lifestyle - perwcfoperation not recreating new instances

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, castle-windsor

I'm using Castle windsor wcf facility to self host my services. Am hosting through windows service.

Am using below code for registering my services -

```
 container.Register(
            Classes
                .FromThisAssembly()
                .Pick()
                .If(x => x.IsClass && HasServiceContract(x))
                .WithServiceDefaultInterfaces()
                .LifestylePerWcfOperation()
                .Configure(c => c.AsWcfService()));
```

I have listed all the endpoints in the app.config file and it will host them using net.tcp binding.

Problem am facing is, even though lifestyle is set as perWcfOperation, a new instance of the XXservice is not getting created per operation. Am assuming that "perWcfOperation" is exactly similar to "InstanceMode.PerCall" in Wcf. If that is the case then why a new object instances are not created for every call?

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Sai

Comment: Did you read: http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.WCF-Facility-Registration.ashx

Comment: @Marwijn, yes I did. BTW, that link has outdated configuration details. As it was using "ActAs" instead of "AsWcfService". "ActAs" is now  deprecated.

Comment: Added this to the class solved my problem: [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]